# Segmentation error in c

Tags: c, list

I am trying to execute the code below but it give back a segmentation message.
I am trying to inizialize a list and after to inlude a first node(cabecera) and print the data, but it give back a segmentation error.
Please help me, dont know whats the problem.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODO{
    float data;
    struct nodo* next;
    struct nodo* before;
} nodo;

typedef struct CABECERA{
    float data;
    struct nodo* next;
} cabecera;

void init(cabecera *L){
    L=NULL;
}

void pushBack(cabecera *L, float e){
    cabecera *newnodo;
    newnodo= (cabecera*)malloc(sizeof(cabecera));
    newnodo->next= NULL;
    newnodo->data=e;
    L=newnodo;
}

int main(){
    cabecera *milista;
    init(milista);
    pushBack(milista, 0.5);
    printf("%f\n", milista->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void init(cabecera *L){
L=NULL;` you're not initializing anything, you're just setting a local variable to `NULL`. Same goes for your push_back method.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre L is a pointer, why should it be an issue?

Comment: @Shiva: it is a pointer, but passed by value. Assigning to `L` has no effect outside that function.

Comment: @Shiva because in `main` they try to access a member of a struct pointer that points nowhere

Comment: Also, `pushBack` is leaking memory

Comment: Modding only a local pointer is a very common problem with C linked lists on SO, as any diligent search would show.  So is failure to debug, either with a real debugger, printfs' or whatever.  'Please help me, dont know whats the problem' is not good enough:(

Answer (score 0):

Indent your code.

To find the problem, compile your program with -g and run it in valgrind, it will tell you exactly what and where the problem is.

Always write in english, it fits with the rest of C and makes it easier for others to understand and help you.

You're not using the node struct you made, but you're referencing it anyway.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                                              


typedef struct NODO{                                                            
    float data;                                                             
    struct nodo* next;                                                      
    struct nodo* before;                                                    
} nodo;                                                                         

    typedef struct CABECERA{                                                        
    float data;                                                             
    struct nodo* next;                                                      
} cabecera;                                                                     


void init(cabecera **L){                                                        
    *L=NULL;                                                                 
}                                                                               



void pushBack(cabecera **L, float e){ //You want to take a pointer to your pointer                                     
    cabecera *newnodo;                                                      
    newnodo= (cabecera*)malloc(sizeof(cabecera));                           
    newnodo->next= NULL;                                                    
    newnodo->data=e;                                                        
    *L=newnodo; // Here you want to modify the VALUE of your pointer.                                             
}                                                                               

int main(){                                                                     
    cabecera *milista;                                                      

    init(&milista); // For init (and pushBack) to modify the value of the pointer, pass a pointer to it.

    pushBack(&milista, 0.5);                                                

    printf("%f\n", milista->data);                                          

    return 0;                                                               
}
```

Here's a toy implementation I did 2 years ago, which can iterate both ways, access element by index (using shortest-path) and convert to/from array. https://github.com/DusteDdk/list

Comment: I have just started programming and I see by your comments that my program is a mesh. Thank you very much and there are some part that have no sense.

Comment: That's okay and normal :) Best of luck with your endeavor, learning C is a rewarding experience.